# Convert List to DataTable leaves blank's {}

Tags: c#, list, file, datatable, dataset

I have never converted a list to a `DataTable` and write it on a text file but in my attempt my file appears all blank only containing empty braces({})
this is my code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in db.Pos)
{
    var total = 0;
    decimal costo = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        var value = 0;

        if (item.Fecha.Day == i) 
        { 
            value = item.Cantidad; 
            costo = costo + item.Total; 
        }

        total += value;
    }

    list.Add(item.Descripcion);
    list.Add(item.Pdv);
    list.Add(item.Rid);
    list.Add(((costo / (total + 1)).ToString("C")));

    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        var value = 0;
        list.Add(value.ToString());
        int month = item.Fecha.Month;

        if (item.Fecha.Day == i) 
        { 
            value = item.Cantidad; 
            list.Add(value.ToString()); 
        }
    }

    list.Add(total.ToString());
    list.Add((((costo / (total + 1)) * total).ToString("C")));   
}
DataTable table = ToDataTable(list);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"\path.txt", table);
```

This is my function that convert my `List<T>` to `DataTable` but makes my file empty:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
{

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

    //Get all the properties
    PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
    {
        //Setting column names as Property names
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
    }

    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        var values = new object[Props.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
        {
            //inserting property values to datatable rows
            values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
        }

        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: You may be converting a list to a datatable but that is not what you are saving....you are saving a 'json' whatever that is.   [Update] Someone edited your question and accidentally removed the saving code.

Comment: yes an apology for that someone edited my question and ereased that part of the code, i just added the part i invoke my converted list function and and write the result to a file

Answer (score 1):

You haven't passed the data table to the WriteAllText method besides the WriteAllText method doesn't have a parameter for a data table. You will need to loop through the data table and write it manually like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/244929/How-to-write-datatable-result-in-textfile

Comment: but for this, my list have to be converted to a datatable right? so know i just need to write it manually like your example after the part where i invoke the functin to convert my list?

Comment: I don't think it is necessary for you to convert your list to a data table to write it to a file unless you are using it for some other purpose. You could just loop through the list and write it out. That way your program will not do unnecessary work.

Comment: my goal is to get the list to a JqueryDatatable but im unable to do so because when i write the list to a file the format is invalid and a better one or a suitable one wuold be in form of a datatable thtas why im trying to convert it unles imm doing the wrong approach

Comment: If you need to convert data table to Jason try this: http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1082/convert-datatable-to-json-in-c